# Yii2 ActiveForm removes help-block after submit button click

Tags: php, forms, yii2

My problem is that after click submit button it removes `<div class="help-block">` with error messages regardless of form is validated or not. It shows only after page refresh. As you can see at images below, when input is empty it gets red border and an error message below, but after submit button click error message is removed, but red border stays. In console i have one POST send after every click, doesn't matter is form validated, but if it's validate there is two POST.
As I noticed, when i type into input email something that is not an email adress and push submit button its shows help-block with message about wrong email adress. Help-block is removed only, when email input is empty.
[it is on blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLJMo.png)

[it is after submit button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v4Dy.png)

Below is my code.

view:

```
<div class="email">
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'email-form',
                    'action' => ['polisy/wyslij'],
                    'errorCssClass' => 'input-error',
                    ]); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'emailAdress')->input('email',[
                        'class' => 'form_renewal',
                        'placeholder' => 'podaj adres email',
                    ]
                )->label(false);?>
                <span class="spacer_email"></span>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'renewalSelect')->dropdownList([
                        'renewal' => 'odnowienie', 
                        'reminder' => 'przypomnienie',
                    ],
                    [
                        'class' =>'renewal-select',
                        'id' => 'renewal-select',
                    ]
                )->label(false); ?>

                <span class="plus" style="display: none;">&#43</span>
                    <?/*= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput([
                            'class' => 'form_renewal', 
                            'placeholder'=>'nazwa szablonu / tytuł',
                        ]
                    )->label(false) */?>
                <span class="save icon-save" style="display: none;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'email_text')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
                    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
                    'language' => 'pl',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'plugins' => [
                            "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
                            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
                        ],
                        'toolbar' => "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
                    ]
                ])->label(false);?>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn_submit " id="row_submit_btn">
                <?= Html::submitButton('wyślij email', ['class' => 'btn btn_modal']) ?>
            </div>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
```

validation rules:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['emailAdress', 'renewalSelect','email_text'], 'required', 'message' => 'pole wymagane'],
            ['emailAdress', 'email', 'message' => 'to nie jest prawidłowy adres email'],
        ];
}
```

and controller:

```
public function actionWyslij(){
  $model = new RenewalForm();
  $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
  if ($model->validate()) {
    $params = array(
        'loginName' => '',
        'agencyID' => ,
        'data' => array(
            'type' => 'email',
            'email' => $model->getEmailAdress(),
            'title' => $model->getTitle(),
            'message' => $model->getEmailText()
            ) 
        );
    $send = Yii::$app->api->call('/notification/send', $params);
    if($send){
      Yii::$app->api->getResponse();
      return $this->redirect('odnowienia?sent=true');
    }
    else {
      return $this->redirect('odnowienia?sent=false');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not validating the form on submit. try to comment thevalidateOnSubmit or make it true. it is not clear to me that you are using ajax validation. update your vendor dir once

Comment: i forgot to set up validate on submit to true back, i change this to false only for test. Inside vendor are these folders: 2amigos       bin    composer  ezyang      phpspec      yiisoft
alcad         bower  doctrine  fzaninotto  swiftmailer
autoload.php  cebe   egulias   jasig       tinymce. I am first time using yii2 and i just have add some features in existing app.

Comment: For first time user see the Contact Us Form Automatically gerenated in initial app. for refrence. you don't need any amigos to code

Comment: found problem, it was removed by js in different file.